# How to make curve closed?

Tags: bezier-curves, path

[image: an open curve]

How can I close a curve / path / to make it closed shape ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]